# cannot run image xampp in docker

Tags: linux, docker, dockerfile, xampp

I wrote a Dockerfile myself then I built it into an image but when I run that image it doesn't work, can you help me?

Dockerfile:

```
FROM ubuntu:latest


# Install XAMPP
RUN apt update && apt install -y wget && apt install net-tools
RUN rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*
RUN wget -O xampp-installer  https://psychz.dl.sourceforge.net/project/xampp/XAMPP%20Linux/8.2.12/xampp-linux-x64-8.2.12-0-installer.run 
RUN chmod 755 xampp-installer
RUN ./xampp-installer

# Expose ports for Apache and MySQL
EXPOSE 80 3306

# Start XAMPP
CMD ["/opt/lampp/lampp", "start"]
```

CLI
[image: cli image]

[image: second cli image]

I tried the related articles but it doesn't correct the problem I'm having

Comment: "but when I run that image it doesn't work" - what's the problem exactly?

Comment: @Alex i run docker run it doesn't work

Comment: You need to be more specific

Comment: once `/opt/lampp/lampp` finishes running, the container terminates. A running Apache2 and MariaDB (not MySQL) instances within the container won't keep it running.

Comment: I want to run xampp images but it cannot run and I check with docker ps and there are no containers running.

Comment: Your image of text [isn't very helpful](//unix.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4086).  It can't be read aloud or copied into an editor, and it doesn't index very well, meaning that other users with the same problem are less likely to find the answer here.  Please [edit] your post to incorporate the relevant text directly (preferably using copy+paste to avoid transcription errors).

Answer (score 2):

The issue is that `/opt/lampp/lampp start` launches a few background tasks and then terminates. When it terminates the container terminates too.

You need a persistent foreground task to keep the container running. One approach to this is to use `tail -f` to monitor the error log.

```
FROM ubuntu:latest

RUN apt update -q && \
    apt install -q -y wget net-tools && \
    rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/* && \
    wget -O xampp-installer "https://psychz.dl.sourceforge.net/project/xampp/XAMPP Linux/8.2.12/xampp-linux-x64-8.2.12-0-installer.run" && \
    chmod 755 xampp-installer && \
    ./xampp-installer

EXPOSE 80 3306

CMD /opt/lampp/lampp start && tail -f /opt/lampp/logs/error_log
```

Another option would be to tack on something like `while true; do sleep 1000; done` at the end of your `CMD` statement.

Your approach also creates multiple services running in the same container. Specifically

- MySQL
- Apache and
- ProFPTD.

It might be a better idea to have each of these running in a separate container, which could be neatly orchestrated by Docker Compose. But the above setup should work fine if you're not a purist!